# include file from another scrapy project

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

In scrapy project: `jobs`, I have an `output_json.py` with `class JsonPipeline`.

I want to ask can I include it directly in another spider called `fan` like:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'fan.pipelines.FandangoPipeline': 100,                
    # 'jobs.output_json.JsonPipeline': 250,    #how to include this??
}
```

So I don't have to copy the file into `fan` project .
Please guide me thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `jobs` package is on the [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path), it would work:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'fan.pipelines.FandangoPipeline': 100,                
    'jobs.output_json.JsonPipeline': 250
}
```

Though, I would not do that since it isn't quite right to have one scrapy project being dependent on an another. Better extract the pipeline into a separate project and reuse in both scrapy projects.

FYI, for the sake of an example, here is a [`fake-useragent` pipeline](https://github.com/alecxe/scrapy-fake-useragent) I've put on github that I use in different projects as a dependency.